# Efficient way to convert data frame to proportions

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` and I would like to divide each cell by the sum of its row using R.

```
set.seed(10);a <- sample(c(1:100), 5)
set.seed(11);b <- sample(c(1:100), 5)
set.seed(12);c <- sample(c(1:100), 5)

df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))

>df
>  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
>a 51 31 42 68  9
>b 28  1 51  2  7
>c  7 81 93 27 17
```

Looking at similar posts, I saw that usually it is recommended to use either `scale` or `apply`.
I found that using simply `df/rowSums(df)`works for me:

```
          V1         V2        V3         V4         V5
a 0.25373134 0.15422886 0.2089552 0.33830846 0.04477612
b 0.31460674 0.01123596 0.5730337 0.02247191 0.07865169
c 0.03111111 0.36000000 0.4133333 0.12000000 0.07555556
```

To achieve the same result with `scale` or `apply` I would need to type respectively

```
as.data.frame(t(scale(t(df), center = FALSE, scale = rowSums(df))))
```

and

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(i) i/sum(i)))
```

Both methods seem a bit...clunkier compared to `df/rowSums(df)`.

My question is: are there any real differences between `scale`, `apply` and  `df/rowSums(df)`or is it just a matter of personal preferences? Maybe I am not using the first two in the most efficient way?

Using `df/rowSums(df)` seems such an easy and short solution. Are there any non-obvious issues with it?

Comment: Do they all run fast enough for your application? If so, then i would go with the most readable one. If df/rowSums(df) works for you then that is pretty clear what is happening. The other methods require a lot more thinking to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use data.table framework. But I like your idea with transposition...

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
ma_func <- function(df){
  df = t(df)
  for (col in names(df)){
    set(df, NULL, col, df[[col]] / sum(df[[col]]))
  }
  df = t(df)
}
```

In my_func, I transpose the data.table, perform transformation col by col and transpose it back.

Now to benchmark the different versions:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  res1 <- df/rowSums(df),
  res2 <- as.data.frame(t(scale(t(df), center = FALSE, scale = rowSums(df)))),
  res3 <- t(apply(df, 1, function(i) i/sum(i))),
  res4 <- ma_func(df)
)
```

And the results are:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                                                        expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
                                                      res1 <- df/rowSums(df) 641.908 663.4615 745.1004 706.1280 775.920 1148.631   100
 res2 <- as.data.frame(t(scale(t(df), center = FALSE, scale = rowSums(df)))) 185.623 201.4580 230.4596 212.4545 237.820  400.863   100
                               res3 <- t(apply(df, 1, function(i) i/sum(i))) 102.049 111.7255 145.5423 123.8950 140.170 1589.082   100
                                                         res4 <- ma_func(df)  51.611  61.1410 116.7342  65.5405  73.897 4825.307   100
```

As you can see my_func is in median twice faster than any other.

And with more columns it will get better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very informative answer and comparison. It looks like `df/rowSums(df)` is consistently the worst performer here, time-wise at least. I wonder what caused that 4800+ spike in the ma_func.